# VB singling out a picturebox from a collection

Tags: vb.net, collections, picturebox

I'm trying to get information from a picturebox from a collection. For example I have 100 pictureboxs in a collection and when I click one it'll load up a new form with all it's information (what image it is, size so on). How will I be able to do this? Is it even possible to do this in a collection or not?

Edit: I'm trying to make a program that builds maps for video games (like the NES version of Legend of Zelda). So these pictureboxs are going be a overview for all the tiles in the game. So what I'm trying to do is when you click on the picturebox, I want a new form to open so then a artist can edit what this tile. I have the editing part done, however I can't find away to get from one form to the other without having 100 click events (I don't want to do that). Anyone know?

Thanks!
Liam

Comment: I dont know where the "collection" bit is coming from.  But simply wiring up the picturebox click event should do the trick.

Comment: Hard to tell what is being asked here.  Parhaps you could explain what you want to do and let us offer some ideas, rather than proposing a specific solution (collection) and have us guess what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `System.Collections.Dictionary(Of String, PictureBox)` or  `System.Collections.Dictionary(Of Integer, PictureBox)` and keep track of the name or number of the pictureBox you're adding, you can do stuff like

```
Console.WriteLine myPictureBoxCollection["pictureBoxName"].Width
```

or

```
For Each pBox As PictureBox in myPictureBoxCollection
   Console.WriteLine pBox.Width
Next pBox
```

This assumes that you've done something like the following to add in your PictureBoxed to the collectio.:

```
Dim myPictureBoxCollection As System.Collections.Dictionary(Of String, PictureBox)
myPictureBoxCollection.Add(PictureBox.Name, PictureBox)
```